# "APIENTRY _tWinMain" and "WINAPI WinMain" difference

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winmain

What are the difference from these 2 function?:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
```

Comment: if you defined _UNICODE, then the second example would error because LPTSTR would be WSTR and wouldn't fit with WinMain, both WINAPI and APIENTRY are defined as __stdcall

Comment: Right click on _tWinMain -> choose go to definition...

Comment: Your WinMain() declaration isn't correct, the 3rd argument is LPSTR.  Both are archaic, you should be using wWinMain today.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**`_tWinMain` is just a `#define` shortcut in tchar.h to the appropriate version of `WinMain`.**

If `_UNICODE` is defined, then `_tWinMain` expands to `wWinMain`. Otherwise, `_tWinMain` is the same as `WinMain`.

The relevant macro looks something like this (there's actually a lot of other code interspersed):

```
#ifdef  _UNICODE
#define _tWinMain  wWinMain
#else
#define _tWinMain  WinMain
#endif
```

Answer (score 28):

The difference is the encoding of the parameters, which are completely redundant anyway.  Just throw away the parameters and instead use the following, where you control the encoding:

`hInstance` is just `GetModuleHandle(0)`

`hPrevInstance` is not valid in Win32 anyway

`lpCmdLine` is available in both ANSI and Unicode, via `GetCommandLineA()` and `GetCommandLineW()`, respectively

`nCmdShow` is the `wShowWindow` parameter of the `STARTUPINFO` structure.  Again, ANSI and Unicode variants, accessed using `GetStartupInfoA(STARTUPINFOA*)` and `GetStartupInfoW(STARTUPINFOW*)`.

And by using the Win32 APIs to access these, you're probably going to save a few global variables, like the one where you were carefully saving the instance handle you thought was only available to `WinMain`.

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/134753-quotwinmainquot-as-quot_twinmainquot/):

> _tWinMain actually does take the hPrevInstance parameter, but that
>   parameter isn''t used.
>
> _tWinMain is just a #define to WinMain (in TCHAR.h).
>
> There is no difference between the
>   two.

and

> _tWinMain is defined to WinMain if UNICODE is not defined, and to
>   wWinMain if it is. its purpose is to
>   let you write code that will build
>   both under ansi and under unicode.

Comment: Other posts further down on the same page you link to suggest that they are not exactly the same. The difference between the two depends on whether or not `_UNICODE` is defined.