# What option do I set to use main() instead of wmain()

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

I have a working Visual Studio project that uses `wmain()` as the entry-point.  I would like to use `main()` instead.

If I simply change the function signature to `int main()`, I get:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wmain referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl mainCRTStartupHelper(struct HINSTANCE__
>   *,unsigned short const *)"

What option do I need to change to make the link succeed?

Comment: Project > Properties > General > Character Set

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: This sounded promising.  I found it at `Configuration Properties > General > Character Set`.  There are three options: `Not Set`, `Use Unicode Character Set`, and `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.  None of them seem to work.

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce the issue. I've just created a brand new Win32 Console project. I can change freely between `main`, `wmain` and `_tmain` without touching project settings, and the project builds fine. As a very long shot, do you have anything under Linker > Advanced > Entry Point?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Your suggestion about the Entry Point was spot on -- I found a solution by messing with that (see my posted answer).  I think there is a bit more to it, since it can work with an empty `Entry Point` (I discovered this by creating a project from scratch as you did).  With my existing project, I am not able to use an empty `Entry Point` (unresolved `_WinMain`), but at least I have found something that works.  --Thanks for the help.

Comment: Regarding `WinMain` vs `main`: Linker > System > SubSystem. Change from Windows to Console. You want Entry Point to be empty except in certain highly unusual situations.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785157/replacing-winmain-with-main-function-in-win32-programs

Comment: For the record regarding an earlier comment: "highly unusual situations" are my speciality. :)  I think in this case I was targeting (embedded) Windows CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by guessing.

`Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced > Entry Point`

was: `mainWCRTStartup`

now: `mainCRTStartup` ## removed `W`

Build succeeded.

Comment: It is not possible to use in project that uses libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this [pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) in your source file, before `int main()`.

> #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")

In Visual Studio project configuration, change *Character Set* to [Use Multi-Byte Character Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) .

Comment: This solution is not working.
'/ENTRY:mainwCRTStartup' not compatible with switch '/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup'; ignored