# Create Win32 window without WinMain function

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I want to write me a small window framework for OpenGL on windows.
I know there are a lot of good window libraries but I like to do it myself.
But I have a small problem, if I want to create a window with the Win32 API I need the parameters like "hInstance" ....
How I get this needed variables in a Window.class ?
How the other Window libraries do it ?

Comment: I probably missed the point of the question, but is there something stopping you from requiring the "client" of your library initiate setup steps by *providing* required data, such as the `hInstance` of the module?

Comment: All the `WinMain` parameters are available without having a `WinMain` -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/25250854/103167

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`GetModuleHandle(0);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the programs `hInstance`. Just passing `0` as the `hInstance` parameter worked for me.

"Passing 0 retrieves the handle of the calling **process**, not the calling **module**. If the library/framework is implemented as a DLL, you would end up with the wrong handle. Use the handle passed to `DllMain()` or `DllEntryPoint()` instead. –  [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)"

Comment: Passing 0 retrieves the handle of the calling **process**, not the calling **module**.  If the library/framework is implemented as a DLL, you would end up with the wrong handle.  Use the handle passed to `DllMain()` or `DllEntryPoint()` instead.

Comment: Saying "worked for me" is kind of pointless when the documentation you link to explains what happens when 0 is passed: *If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleHandle returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file).*

Comment: @chris I meant as the hInstance parameter, not as the parameter to `GetModuleHandle`. I edited to make that clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11785762/1462718  @OP doesn't mention that they're framework is in a dll. They did not tag dll or dynamic link library either. It's SAFE to assume they are just replacing winmain with main and so `GetModuleHandle(0)` is fine for that purpose.