# What is the correct way to define a UNICODE independent WinMain function?

Tags: winapi, unicode, linker, winmain

What is the correct way to define a `UNICODE` independent `WinMain` function for a Windows program that uses the CRT?

I am inclined to think that it should be something like

```
WINAPI
#ifdef UNICODE
  wWinMain
#else
  WinMain
#endif
 ( ... ) {
  ...
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is not already a predefined macro that expands to the correct symbol when compiling the source units (like those that are offered in the windows header files that expand to either `WinApiFuncA` or `WinApiFuncW`.

Comment: `_tWinMain` macro defined in *tchar.h* and expanded to `wWinMain` or `WinMain`

Comment: So, do I have to include `<tchar.h>`?

Comment: i think it indirect already included

Comment: look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/4681487/6401656

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["APIENTRY \_tWinMain" and "WINAPI WinMain" difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681443/apientry-twinmain-and-winapi-winmain-difference)

Comment: @Axalo: this is not about the differente of `WinMain` or `wWinMain` or `_tWinMain`, it's about how I correctly (or canonically) define `WinMain` in my source code.

Comment: @RbMm I don't think so. When I do a quick search for `#include.*tchar.h` in the CRT sources, I only find `.c` sources that include this file, but no `.h` sources.

Comment: @René You should use the Unicode variants as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/unicode).

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger RbMms first comment is the answer. And yes you need to include `<tchar.h>`.

Comment: Why would you want to support ANSI?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this question may be of interest to you OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant

Comment: People still supporting ANSI 15 years after it went out of style :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `<tchar.h>`, the macro `_tWinMain` expands to `WinMain`  or `wWinMain` depending on project settings. This isn't enough, though; you need to declare the third argument (`lpCmdLine`) with the charset-agnostic `LPTSTR` too:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance, 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPTSTR lpCmdLine, 
    int nShowCmd
)
```

If Unicode is enabled on the project, this becomes `LPWSTR`, giving the signature:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance, 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPWSTR lpCmdLine, 
    int nShowCmd
)
```

If Unicode is not enabled, you get the signature:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance, 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
    int nShowCmd
)
```